# Cordova app: Remote Build to iOS

Tags: javascript, cordova, xcode8

I have a problem with remote building my Cordova on my host macBook. I get an error that says Build failed with error Command to fetch Xcode Version failed.

This was done through Visual Studio 2017.

So I assumed that maybe the VS tool for Apache Cordova wasn't configured properly. So, I tried to build using the `>taco build iOS CLI` and I got an error saying:

> "an invalid cordova versionsionSpecifier: Error: 8.0.0"

[Building through CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBFOI.pmg)

[build.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMh7r.png)

[Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UBNt.png)

Comment: please view attached images. for a descriptive error....

Comment: and  using Xcode 8.3 and cordova 8.0.0